# Clarification on how a particular space is defined

Tags: analysis, metric-spaces, cauchy-sequences

I am tasked with proving that the the metric space $(C[0,1], d)$ is complete where $d$ is the infinity-metric.

As of right now, I interpret the set $C[0,1]$ as the set of continuous functions from $0$ to $1$, but I find the idea of calculating a distance between elements in this space to be very abstract. Could someone tell me what the infinity-metric means when applied to the set $C[0,1]$, or at least provide me with some sort of clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that
$$
d(f,g)=\sup_{x\in[0,1]}|f(x)-g(x)|
$$
In particular $f_n\to f$ in this metric means precisely that $f_n\to f$ uniformly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You're assuming that f(x) and g(x) are arbitrarily chosen continuous functions from 0 to 1, right?

Comment: Also, are these functions from $R$ to $R$? Or can they  be from $R^m$ to $R^n$ for any natural numbers m and n?

Comment: Not functions from 0 to 1, but rather functions from $[0,1]$ to $\Bbb{R}$.

Answer (score 0):

Foobaz John tells what the metric in $C[0,1]$ is. Also that metric comes from the norm $$\vert\vert f \vert \vert=\sup_{x \in C[0,1]} \vert f(x) \vert$$

Also you understand what they are, see this picture:[image]